# how to optimize query

Tags: mysql

Is there any single query to delete the child tables if the parent table will be deleted?

tables:

t1

t1_id
 1

t2

t2_id          t1_id
 1                1
 2                1

t3

t3_id           t2_id
 1                  1 
 2                  1
 3                  1

t4

t4_id      t3_id
 1             1
 2             1

So if I will delete t1_id =1 , all children rows must also be deleted to avoid orphan data...
In this case all data in these 4 tables should be deleted..
Is there any single line of query how to this?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at using

[FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

with `ON DELETE CASCADE`

> CASCADE: Delete or update the row from
>   the parent table and automatically
>   delete or update the matching rows in
>   the child table.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to define foreign keys and declare the tables to cascade on delete.
Have a look to the [SQL syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).